# Umask not working

Tags: bash, umask

I'm trying to figure out how to use `umask`.

I ran `umask 027` expecting this would result in all permissions for myself, read and execute for group, and none for everyone else.

*Based on a default of 777 minus 027 = 750.*

But when I run:

```
umask 027
touch test
ls -l test
```

I get back:

```
-rw-r----- 1 philip philip 0 Jun  3 12:14 test
```

This is not at all what I was expecting.

Where did I go wrong in my understanding of `umask`?

Comment: The default (and maximum) for a file is 666; for a directory it is 777. Try making a directory and checking. Depending on your distro, you may be able to do `umask -S` to obtain some additional information. Also, it is not actually "subtraction" as implied, but a bitwise operation. Please see [How is umask calculated in Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84676/how-is-umask-calculated-in-linux?rq=1).

Comment: I think your assumption of default value is not correct for files. `777` is for directories, whereas `666` is for files. So in your case, `666-027` will result in `640` as you get in result. More info here: https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How umask works](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/211481/how-umask-works)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The umask cannot add permissions, it only servers to mask away some of the permission bits set by the process creating the file in question.

> The umask is used by `open(2)`, `mkdir(2)`, and other system calls that
>          create files to modify the permissions placed on newly created files
>          or directories.  Specifically, permissions in the umask are turned
>          off from the mode argument to `open(2)` and `mkdir(2)`.

([manual page `umask(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/umask.2.html))

`touch` creates files with permissions `0666`, as most other applications do when not creating something explicitly known to be private, or something that should be executable (in which case they'd use `0600` or `0777` respectively). If the `umask` could be used to force adding permission bits, stuff like email clients and `ssh-keygen` would be in trouble: they'd have no way to create files that can only be accessed by the owner!

```
$ umask 027; rm xxx; strace -etrace=open touch xxx 2>&1 | grep xxx ;  ls -l xxx
open("xxx", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK, 0666) = 3
-rw-r----- 1 itvirta itvirta 0 Jun  3 20:40 xxx
```

If we arrange for the file to be created with wider permissions, we see the execute bits too:

```
$ umask 027; rm yyy; 
$ perl -MFcntl -e 'sysopen F, "yyy", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0777'
$ ls -l yyy
-rwxr-x--- 1 itvirta itvirta 0 Jun  3 20:40 yyy*
```

Similarly we could create a directory without the `x` bits set...

```
$ perl -MFcntl -e 'mkdir "ddd", 0666'
$ ls -ld  ddd
drw-r----- 2 itvirta itvirta 4096 Jun  3 20:45 ddd/
```