# Umask to make default permission 750

Tags: permissions, umask

I'm working through questions from [Unix The Textbook](https://www.amazon.ca/Unix-Textbook-Syed-Mansoor-Sarwar/dp/032122731X).

I'm trying to solve the question *(chapter 8, #15, page 207)*:

> 15. Give a command line for setting the default access mode so that you have read, write, and execute privileges, your group has read and
>       execute privileges, your group has read and execute  permissions, and
>       all others have no permission for a newly created executable file or
>       directory. How would you test it to be sure that it works correctly?

My initial answer was to use `umask 027`, but [I found that](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/369012/umask-not-working) creating a new file with `touch` or `vim` never worked as expected for the execute permission as `umask` was applied to `666` not `777`.

Since my end goal is to have a permission value of `750` it seems to me it is impossible with the `umask` command as any `umask` applied to `666` will not result in `750`.

Given all the questions in this section relate to `chmod` and `umask` is the question flawed in that you can't achieve the desired goal using `umask`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the question contains this part:

> for a newly created executable file or directory.

Newly created executables and directories are probably created with mode 0777, so they would get the execute permissions as wanted, too. So the question seems to be correctly stated and an umask of 027 should do.

Comment: Do you now where I can see the `touch` command if I want to modify it? I assume it is a C file somewhere.

Comment: I guess I could just run `which touch`

Comment: or not that shows me a compiled version

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride, depends on the OS. GNU `touch` is part of [GNU coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html). Of course your system may have its own method for distributing source (SRPMs, `apt-get source`, etc.)

Comment: Thanks posting link so I can find it later, cheers https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/7ea15a57c7a8b876daa3d4d01f1192af3f58f3c7/src/touch.c

Answer (score 0):

Per [these docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/817-3814/userconcept-95347/index.html) you can determine any umask by subtracting from 777 (666 advised for files because they're not exectuable by default).

So you can something like

```
PERM=750
UMASK=$(expr 777 - $PERM)
echo $UMASK
>>> 27
```

Note, it's missing that leading zero which might be an issue in some contexts, but works fine if you just want