# File create permission error although dir has 777 permission

Tags: linux, files, permissions, filesystems, strace

On running command `touch file`
I am getting error

```
touch: cannot touch 'file': permission denied
```

Although I have 777 permissions on the dir where I am trying to create file but still not able to create file with one particular user, some other users can create files there.

Tried `strace` to see what might be root cause but not able to to understand strace output.
One line and I guess relevant as well of  strace output is:

```
open("file", O_WRONGLY|O_CREATE|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK, 0666) = -1  EACESS (Permission denied)
```

I tried to create file with specific permissions as well but getting permission error, command tried is:

```
install -b -m 511 /dev/null file
```

Comment: Is the user that cannot create a file in the directory able to navigate (i.e., `cd`) to that directory?

Comment: @AndyDalton yes

Comment: Does a file with that name already exist, and if so is it owned by a different user?

Comment: Please check this answer. [https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/369012/umask-not-working](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/369012/umask-not-working)

Comment: @AndyDalton no file is there with this name I tried with other names as well

Comment: @user3411123 the question you gave looks like completely different to me

Answer (score 2):

Possibly it is overriden by a filesystem access control list. Possibly Linux ACL? You may determine that by using `lsfacl`.

**Get current ACL** - You can check permissions for any file or directory with getfacl. See example below.

`# getfacl dir/
 file: dir
 owner: root
 group: root
user::rwx
group::---
other::---`

**Set permissions with ACL** -
You may set "mode" 0777 for a directory with inheritance in the access control lists with `setfacl -d -m o::rwx /directory`

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue as well. For me, the problem was that I had given the necessary rwx permissions to the parent directory:

```
chmod 777 parent_dir
```

but I was trying to `touch` a file in a subdirectory that I didn't had permission to.

```
> touch parent_dir/subdir/file.txt
touch: cannot touch 'parent_dir/subdir/file.txt': Permission denied
```

If this is your issue, the command you are looking for is, for example

```
chmod -R 777 parent_dir
```

Answer (score -1):

Some time you have sufficient permission on the current directory in which you want to create file but don't have permission on parent directories in hierarchy .

Please see that once , if there are some permission problems from Root directory to your current directory .

One Other reason may be , check selinux is enabled or not .

Comment: Can you explain this **sometimes** case, why it might happen ? Although this is not true in my case. Generally users doesn't have access to all parent dirs in hierarchy.

Comment: If the OP can get to the directory in question, parent permissions have no more relevance.